# How can I further improve the efficiency and speed of my string class

Tags: c++, string

I was inspired by CString class in MFC. After I understood the principle of that class, especially CopyBeforeWrite technology. I attempted to further improve its efficiency. So I wrote an EspString class.

In CString, there is a CStringData for sharing buffer when assigned a already existed CString object to a new one. Specifically, when we wrote CString szNew(szOld) or CString szNew = szOld, initially, they share the same buffer, until one of them is modified (that it will call CopyBeforeWrite function, allocate to a new buffer and allow CStringData::nRef-1).

My code: (most of them are repeated, I inserted the data to struct rather than use (char*)(this+1) to connect).

Storage Struct:

```
struct EspStringInfo{
/// <summary>
/// > 1 : The buffer is being shared and still can be shared for new string class.
/// = 1 : The buffer can be shared, while it is not shared currently. The initial string will be this value.
/// = -1: The buffer is locked. Although it can be modified, it cannot be shared to any other class. 
/// </summary>
long m_nRef;
unsigned int m_nStrLen;
unsigned int m_nBufSize;
char* m_pszStr;};
```

Two Global Variables:

```
int g_pNullStringData[] = { -1,0,0,NULL };
EspStringInfo* g_pNullStringInfo = (EspStringInfo*)g_pNullStringData;
```

Constructor: (Given the character limit, I only provide some of them, while the principle is similar)

```
EspString(const char& nCh, unsigned int nChCount)
{
    assert(nCh != 0);
    this->m_pStrInfo = new EspStringInfo;
    this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef = 1;
    this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nChCount;
    this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nChCount * 2;
    this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr = new char[this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
    for (unsigned int I = 0; I < nChCount; ++I)
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr[I] = nCh;
    ::memset(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, 0, (this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize - this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen) * sizeof(char));
}

EspString(const EspString& szStr)
{
    if (szStr.m_pStrInfo == g_pNullStringInfo)
    {
        this->m_pStrInfo = g_pNullStringInfo;
        return;
    }
    if (szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_nRef >= 1)
    {
        this->m_pStrInfo = szStr.m_pStrInfo;
        ::InterlockedIncrement(&szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_nRef);
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int nBufSize = szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen * 2;
        this->m_pStrInfo = new EspStringInfo;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef = 1;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nBufSize;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr = new char[nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
        ::memcpy(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen * sizeof(char));
        ::memset(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr + szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, 0, (nBufSize - szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen) * sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Destructor:

```
~EspString()
{
    if (this->m_pStrInfo != g_pNullStringInfo)
    {
        if (::InterlockedDecrement(&this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef) < 1)
        {
            delete[] this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr;
            delete this->m_pStrInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Append: (e.g. szStr="1234"; szStr.Append("56") and then szStr="123456" )

```
EspString& Append(const char& nCh, unsigned int nCount)
{
    if (nCh == 0)
        return *this;

    if (this->m_pStrInfo == g_pNullStringInfo)
    {
        this->m_pStrInfo = new EspStringInfo;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef = 1;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nCount;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nCount * 2;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr = new char[this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
        ::memset(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, nCh, nCount * sizeof(char));
        ::memset(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr + nCount, 0, nCount * sizeof(char));
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int nStrLen = this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen + nCount;
        if (this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef > 1)
        {
            unsigned int nBufSize = nStrLen * 2;
            EspStringInfo* pNewStrInfo = new EspStringInfo;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nRef = 1;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nBufSize;
            pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr = new char[nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
            ::memcpy(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen * sizeof(char));
            ::memset(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, nCh, nCount * sizeof(char));
            ::memset(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr + nStrLen, 0, (nBufSize - nStrLen) * sizeof(char));
            ::InterlockedDecrement(&this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef);
            this->m_pStrInfo = pNewStrInfo;
        }
        else
        {
            if (nStrLen < this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize)
            {
                ::memset(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, nCh, nCount * sizeof(char));
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
            }
            else
            {
                unsigned int nBufSize = nStrLen * 2;
                char* pszNewBuf = new char[nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
                ::memcpy(pszNewBuf, this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen * sizeof(char));
                ::memset(pszNewBuf + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, nCh, nCount * sizeof(char));
                ::memset(pszNewBuf + nStrLen, 0, (nBufSize - nStrLen) * sizeof(char));
                delete[] this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nBufSize;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr = pszNewBuf;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
EspString& Append(const char* pszStr)
{
    if (pszStr == NULL)
        return *this;

    unsigned int nNewStrLen = ::lstrlenA(pszStr);

    if (this->m_pStrInfo == g_pNullStringInfo)
    {
        this->m_pStrInfo = new EspStringInfo;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef = 1;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nNewStrLen;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nNewStrLen * 2;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr = new char[this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
        ::memcpy(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, pszStr, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
        ::memset(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr + nNewStrLen, 0, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int nStrLen = this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen + nNewStrLen;
        if (this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef > 1)
        {
            unsigned int nBufSize = nStrLen * 2;
            EspStringInfo* pNewStrInfo = new EspStringInfo;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nRef = 1;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nBufSize;
            pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr = new char[nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
            ::memcpy(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen * sizeof(char));
            ::memcpy(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, pszStr, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
            ::memset(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr + nStrLen, 0, (nBufSize - nStrLen) * sizeof(char));
            ::InterlockedDecrement(&this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef);
            this->m_pStrInfo = pNewStrInfo;
        }
        else
        {
            if (nStrLen < this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize)
            {
                ::memcpy(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, pszStr, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
            }
            else
            {
                unsigned int nBufSize = nStrLen * 2;
                char* pszNewBuf = new char[nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
                ::memcpy(pszNewBuf, this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen * sizeof(char));
                ::memcpy(pszNewBuf + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, pszStr, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
                ::memset(pszNewBuf + nStrLen, 0, (nBufSize - nStrLen) * sizeof(char));
                delete[] this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nBufSize;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr = pszNewBuf;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
EspString& Append(const EspString& szStr)
{
    if (szStr.m_pStrInfo == g_pNullStringInfo)
        return *this;

    unsigned int nNewStrLen = szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen;

    if (this->m_pStrInfo == g_pNullStringInfo)
    {
        this->m_pStrInfo = new EspStringInfo;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef = 1;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nNewStrLen;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nNewStrLen * 2;
        this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr = new char[this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
        ::memcpy(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
        ::memset(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr + nNewStrLen, 0, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int nStrLen = this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen + nNewStrLen;
        if (this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef > 1)
        {
            unsigned int nBufSize = nStrLen * 2;
            EspStringInfo* pNewStrInfo = new EspStringInfo;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nRef = 1;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
            pNewStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nBufSize;
            pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr = new char[nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
            ::memcpy(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen * sizeof(char));
            ::memcpy(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
            ::memset(pNewStrInfo->m_pszStr + nStrLen, 0, (nBufSize - nStrLen) * sizeof(char));
            ::InterlockedDecrement(&this->m_pStrInfo->m_nRef);
            this->m_pStrInfo = pNewStrInfo;
        }
        else
        {
            if (nStrLen < this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize)
            {
                ::memcpy(this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
            }
            else
            {
                unsigned int nBufSize = nStrLen * 2;
                char* pszNewBuf = new char[nBufSize * sizeof(char)];
                ::memcpy(pszNewBuf, this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen * sizeof(char));
                ::memcpy(pszNewBuf + this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen, szStr.m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr, nNewStrLen * sizeof(char));
                ::memset(pszNewBuf + nStrLen, 0, (nBufSize - nStrLen) * sizeof(char));
                delete[] this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nStrLen = nStrLen;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_nBufSize = nBufSize;
                this->m_pStrInfo->m_pszStr = pszNewBuf;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

There are also some other method, and there is the general process:

1. Judge the m_pStrInfo is g_pNullStringInfo, all null string will point to this pointer.
2. if m_nRef>1, the buffer is being shared.
3. the buffer is not shared.

I wrote this project because in my project the string class have to be assigned to a new object for a lots of times. In the past, the buffer has to be allocated repeatedly and it will waste lots of resources and time. Have there some ways to further improve the efficiency? Thanks for the reply!!!!!!!

Comment: *Have there some ways to further improve the efficiency?* --  *In the past, the buffer has to be allocated repeatedly* --  Attempting copy-on-write strings in this day and age of C++ is a nightmare if you are to use them in anything other than a single-threaded program.  That's why they are basically been outlawed as a way to implement `std::string`.

Comment: If your code hasn't any issue and you just want some advices about making it "better", maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour is a better fit for this question.

Comment: This `EspStringInfo* g_pNullStringInfo = (EspStringInfo*)g_pNullStringData;` will lead to UB if you try to use `g_pNullStringInfo`. A pointer to an array of `int` is not convertible to a pointer to `EspStringInfo`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie    I've read some passage. When two different thread try to modify the same info struct (like CStringData), some problems might occur. Is that true? I can lock and unlock during modifying every time, while the efficiency will decrease dramatically I think, because it is not what I expect.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's what CString implemented. Can I wrote in `EspStringInfo g_pNullStringData={-1,0,0,NULL}` and `EspStringInfo* g_pNullStringInfo=&g_pNullStringData` or use &g_pNullStringData directly?

Comment: @Escapist.Arcadia I'd be interested if you could share where you found this. Still, library implementers are not necessarily constrained by the same rules as their users. Reading standard or platform specific library code is not a useful learning tool because there is no easy way to know if what they are doing is legal C++ or using tricks that only they are allowed to use.

Comment: @Escapist.Arcadia `EspStringInfo g_pNullStringData={-1,0,0,nullptr};` should be OK because `EspStringInfo` is an aggregate type. It will use [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The CString was wrote in this way, at least the version I studied.

Comment: @Escapist.Arcadia I understood that, but can you please provide the file and line number where you saw this? I would like to take a look at it myself.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux https://blog.csdn.net/whf727/article/details/1909531 this is the link from Chinese website and introduces the principle of CString by analyzing its code. You can Ctrl+F and input "string.cpp". But I think this version is a little bit old.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.